# Impressão com conteúdo sempre em uma página?

Tags: javascript, css

Um cliente solicitou que sempre que fosse feito a impressão de uma tabela de preços, fosse sempre impressa somente em uma página, há como fazer isso?

Desde já agradeço a ajuda..

Comment: Kielvi, pode mostrar um pouco dessa sua tabela ? Uma print talvez..

Comment: Giovanni, tu diz o html/css ou o visual?

Comment: [link]http://www.mediafire.com/view/lba6gd8zbst80d8/Captura%20de%20Tela%202016-09-26%20a%CC%80s%2012.10.48.png[/link]

Comment: Aaah, literalmente impressão.. Sei que é possível editar a tela de impressão, mas como vai ser impresso tudo em uma página caso não tenha espaço suficiente? Acredito que não seja possível..

Comment: Pois é, foi isso que tentei passar pra ele, visto que vai ser variado o numeto de itens da tabela para cada empreendimento e não tem como controlar pra sempre a tabela se ajustar somente em uma página.

Comment: Tem como fazer, o ideal é fazer um sistema desktop e não web, tem muito mais controle sobre a impressão. Pra web vai sofrer mesmo. Eu sempre falo que aplicação web não é solução para tudo. Mas pegou uma moda que diz que é. Quem acredita nesse engodo paga o preço.

Comment: Resposta: Sim, há. Essa resposta te ajudou? Certamente não. :) Percebe o problema da sua pergunta? Enfim, seja bem vindo ao SOPT, mas observe que este site *não é um fórum*. Faça o [tour], leia [ask] e edite a pergunta para deixá-la objetiva com alguma dificuldade sua, ok?